# User gets logged out, after post upload [PHP]

Tags: php

I got a problem with my post upload formula and need your help.

With this formula, I inserted data into 2 tables at same time and it worked perfectly fine. My next step was to insert the `userid` in the post table, so that the post is linked to the creator of the post.

Inserting the `userid` in the post table worked as well but after the upload, the user gets logged out.

Here is a part of my code
(I marked the code where I think there is something wrong with a `"X"`)

```
session_start();
$db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "abc");

if (isset($_POST['upload_post']))
{ 
  $ad_post_title = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['post_title']);

X $user_id = $_SESSION['id_u']; 
X $_SESSION['id_u'] = mysqli_insert_id($db);
X $sql_p = "INSERT INTO ad_posts (post_title, user_id) VALUES ('$post_title','$user_id')";

  if (mysqli_query($db, $sql_p))
  {
    $ad_post_id = mysqli_insert_id($db);

    ...

  }
}
```

Maybe I have done something wrong with the session?

Comment: Please give me a full code so I can try to solve.

Comment: From where `mysqli_insert_id($db)` comes when you haven't inserted any record?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the second line of your code you are overwriting a session variable of the users id, which I figure you're using to make sure the user is logged in, with the id of the newly inserted row.

```
   $user_id = $_SESSION['id_u']; 
X  $_SESSION['id_u'] = mysqli_insert_id($db);
   $sql_p = "INSERT INTO ad_posts (post_title, user_id) VALUES ('$post_title','$user_id')";
```

In the code you supplied I do not see are reason for this second line, remove it and your user won't be logged out, unless of course you're overwriting it somewhere else also.

Comment: Thank you, you are right, this was the problem. Now it works! :) But a other question, what is the usage of this "mysqli_insert_id? (i will accept your answer, after the time limit)

Comment: The usage of the mysqli_insert_id is to get the id of the last inserted row.  If you need the id of the row you just inserted call this function.

Answer (score 1):

You cannoT use mysqli_insert_id() before add data in the system.
I checked same code in my system and its working fine.

```
session_start();
$db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "abc");

if (isset($_POST['upload_post']))
{ 
  $ad_post_title = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['post_title']);

 $user_id = $_SESSION['id_u']; 
 $sql_p = "INSERT INTO ad_posts (post_title, user_id) VALUES ('$post_title','$user_id')";

  if (mysqli_query($db, $sql_p))
  {
    $ad_post_id = mysqli_insert_id($db);

    ...

  }
}
```

Comment: what is the usage of "mysqli_insert_id" ? Dawson Irvine answer was to delete this line of code and it worked then, no i also got the id od the user in my post

Comment: You can get last inserted record id(Primary Key) of newly inserted record.